# Displaying an image from mysql in a pdf using pdfkit

Tags: mysql, node.js, pdfkit

I am using node.js, express, mysql and pdfkit to generate a pdf from user input. I also have images in the database which I want to place in the pdf. These are .png images stored in a VARBINARY column in the database. I am actually converting the project from MS SQL Server to Mysql and displaying the images worked when I was using SQL Server, but now it tells me:

```
Unknown Image format
```

My database table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Signatures
(
    SignID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY,
    Signature VARBINARY(65000) NOT NULL,
    -- Signature BLOB NOT NULL,
    UserID_FK INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (UserID_FK)
        REFERENCES Users (UserID)
);
```

My app.js:

```
const sql = `CALL Read_IncidentSignatures_SP(?);`;
const [metaData] = await mysqldb.pool.query(sql, data);
const signatures = metaData[0];

let sign1 = '';
let sign2 = '';

for (const sign of signatures) {
    if (sign.SignaturePos === 1) {
        //sign1 = convertToImage(sign.Signature);
        sign1 = sign.Signature;
    } else if (sign.SignaturePos === 2) {
        sign2 = convertToImage(sign.Signature);
        //sign2 = sign.Signature;
    } 
}

function convertToImage(data) {
    if (data === undefined || data === '') {
        return '';
    }
    var originalBase64ImageStr = new Buffer.from(data).toString('utf8');
    var decodedImage = new Buffer.from(originalBase64ImageStr, 'base64');
    console.log('REACHED HERE');
    return decodedImage;
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?